# Wordpress pages redirect to main page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'm a noob with wordpress and I'm creating a website with it. The thing is I've changed the permalinks to be the name of the entry/page. I've created 2 pages so far, and when I view my website and click on the links to those pages, the url does change to wordpress/page1 or wordpress/page2, but the page shown is always the main page.

I'm working with wamp for windows, so I've been doing some research. This is what I've found so far:

My .htaccess is like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I've also changed the mod_rewrite inside apache httpd.conf removing the # and I've saved changes in permalinks. Nothing is working.

Comment: It is not working neither when using default permalinks.

Comment: Some advances, I've tried using a default wordrpess theme, the pages are shown. When I activate the theme I'm creating, they are not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to make a change in your .htaccess file from:

```
RewriteBase /
```

to the following:

```
RewriteBase /wordpress/
```

Comment: I have done that as well, when I remove the "read only" property in the htaccess file, it changes to rewritebase /worpress/ when I save changes at the permalinks page. It is still not working.

Comment: Try to deactivate all the plugins and check if the problem remains.

Comment: what about deleting the .htaccess file and trying to change the permalinks again?

Comment: wordrpess reinstalled, not working. .htacess deleted and created again, not working. Permalinks changed again, not working. Really disappointed with this thing.

Comment: Are you sure you have the `AllowOverride All` setting enabled in the `httpd.conf` for your specific directory? e.g. `<Directory "PATH_TO_YOUR_WORDPRESS_DIRECTORY">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.

It was not recognizing my single.php